# creating mnesia from an erlang module

Tags: erlang, mnesia

This should be simple, although I could not find a way or example yet...

The Mnesia documentation shows how to initialize/create an Mnesia database from the erlang shell, which requires to start the erl shell with the -mnesia parameter:

```
erl -mnesia dir '"/tmp/funky"'
```

Once in the shell you can create the schema/etc...

```
>mnesia:create_schema([node()]).
ok.
>mnesia:start().
ok.
```

Well, that's simple enough. What if I want to create the schema/etc from another erlang module and I did not start the process with the -mnesia parateter/flag ? I think that basically means, how to dynamically, without running a script but from a pure erlang code approach. For instance, I'd like to do something like this:

```
-module(something).
-export([test/0]).

test() ->
    erlang:setParameter("mnesia","/tmp/funcky"),
    mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I found the solution. set_env is what I needed:

```
application:set_env(mnesia, dir, "/tmp/funcky"),
mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
etc...
```